# could someone explain why we return super().form_valid(form) in form_valid method in CreateView in django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I am trying to link the Item associated with a user

```
class createItem(CreateView):
model=Item
fields = ['x','y','image']


def form_valid(self,form):
    form.instance.user_name=self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

this is the snippet,i dont get why we use `super().form_valid(form)` ,and i also have doubt regarding using self in `self.request.user` ,i am new to django ,it will really helpful if someone assisted me.

Answer (score 0):

`Super()` allows you  to access and modify methods of your base class `(class createItem(CreateView))`.

So in your case, you are inserting the logged-in user id into the form fields, which was not there before when the form was submitted.

`def form_valid` is a method which basically asks "Are the form fields valid?"
If the answer is yes (they are valid), then insert user id as a field. So you are modifying the default behavior of your class on the fly. You do that by invoking super.

May want to read more on inheritance.

Comment: I think he needs to add instance = form.save(commit=False) before adding the user instance to the form

Comment: No form.save(commit=False) is for function views. form_valid is the right one

Comment: Really? I dont think so. I am not talking about form_valid. That is correct. I am talking about inside his form_valid function, he needs to add instance=form.save(commit=False). This tells the form to not save and wait until the user instance has been added. And it is not just for function views. https://dashdrum.com/blog/2011/12/using-form-savecommitfalse-in-a-class-based-view/

Comment: If you look at https://dashdrum.com/blog/2011/12/using-form-savecommitfalse-in-a-class-based-view/, it not calling super. Super will do the save for you with the behaviors inside the function.

Comment: This makes sense now.

Comment: Glad I can help, validate the answer, and come back if you have any more questions

Comment: oh,so first we  changed the default behaviour of form_valid and we again called form_valid in super() to further provide additional functionality of  form_valid? am i right?

Comment: could u also explain that self.request.user part? in here the self refers to the object right,soo how exactly will the user get added to the user field in the form?

Comment: If you got an answer to your question, mark that answer to show gratitude, then Open a new question. That's how this website work.